# Apache misconfiguring httpd.conf

Tags: django, apache

I uploaded the httpd.conf file for the staging django server to the live server and restarted it and that brought the site down. After returning the right file restarting it and stopping staging server I get internal server error roughly once for every 5 refreshes on the page that shows missing info for `top_menu`

```
[Fri Nov 13 11:38:41.793432 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 130327:tid 139718655588096] [remote 127.0.0.1:25256]     result = block.nodelist.render(context)
[Fri Nov 13 11:38:41.793440 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 130327:tid 139718655588096] [remote 127.0.0.1:25256]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render
[Fri Nov 13 11:38:41.793452 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 130327:tid 139718655588096] [remote 127.0.0.1:25256]     bit = self.render_node(node, context)
[Fri Nov 13 11:38:41.793461 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 130327:tid 139718655588096] [remote 127.0.0.1:25256]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 858, in render_node
[Fri Nov 13 11:38:41.793473 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 130327:tid 139718655588096] [remote 127.0.0.1:25256]     return node.render(context)
[Fri Nov 13 11:38:41.793481 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 130327:tid 139718655588096] [remote 127.0.0.1:25256]   File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/mptt/templatetags/mptt_tags.py", line 284, in render
[Fri Nov 13 11:38:41.793495 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 130327:tid 139718655588096] [remote 127.0.0.1:25256]     queryset = self.queryset_var.resolve(context)
[Fri Nov 13 11:38:41.793504 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 130327:tid 139718655588096] [remote 127.0.0.1:25256]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 734, in resolve
[Fri Nov 13 11:38:41.793516 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 130327:tid 139718655588096] [remote 127.0.0.1:25256]     value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
[Fri Nov 13 11:38:41.793524 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 130327:tid 139718655588096] [remote 127.0.0.1:25256]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 780, in _resolve_lookup
[Fri Nov 13 11:38:41.793537 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 130327:tid 139718655588096] [remote 127.0.0.1:25256]     (bit, current))  # missing attribute
[Fri Nov 13 11:38:41.793580 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 130327:tid 139718655588096] [remote 127.0.0.1:25256] VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [top_menu] in u"[{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {}]"
```

which goes to this context proccessor `'top_menu':Page.objects.filter(top_menu=True, visible=True),` and returns the info correctly when I run it from the shell.

```
>>> from pages.models import *
>>> Page.objects.filter(top_menu=True, visible=True)
[<Page: Home>, <Page: What’s On>, <Page: What’s On :: Today>, <Page: What’s On :
: This Weekend>, <Page: What’s On :: This Month>, <Page: Movies>, <Page: Movies
:: Now Showing>, <Page: Lifestyle>, <Page: Biz Directory>, <Page: Buy&Sell >, <P
age: Galleries>, <Page: Newsletters>]
>>>
```

I want to reset the apache server to start working correctly now.

Comment: I can't see why you think this has anything to do with the Apache configuration. Clearly in some views you're not running context processors.

Comment: visit www.kenyabuzz.com and refresh the page like five times you'll get an Internal server error atleast once, during those five times. It applies to every page on the site,

Answer (score 0):

I found the error was with the sys path in the wsgi it was pointing to the wrong path and restarting the server made the error to start coming.